# Reprojecting and splitting in tiles with gdal

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I have downloaded all the [DEMs from the European Environment Agency](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eu-dem), which I would like to use to generate color relief, hillshading and slope shading raster data. As my final map will be in EPSG:3785 a.k.a. WebMercator, I thought of reprojecting the data before any other treatment, because otherwise reprojecting happens on every render. Also, in my personal experience (not much, really), it seems that the rendering engine (Mapnik) works better with tiles grouped with a VRT file on top than with a huge Tiff (we're talking about final data which is 288000x325220 pixels), so the idea is to also reproject the data into another set of tiles, overlapping of possible (like the original SRTM files, if you are familiar with them).

At first I tried reprojecting every 5x5° tile, but this leaves gaps at tile boundary. I don't have those files anymore, but I was definitely experiencing gaps for instance at 60°N.

Then I created a virtual file like so:

```
gdalbuildvrt EU-DEM.vrt *.tif
```

and then tried to wrestle with `gdalwrap`, but I was at a loss on how to specify something like: start at degrees XxY, this amount of pixels +1 wide, as tall as needed (+1 pixel). It's true that I could use `-ts` for the last part (but not exactly), but `-te` was not good enough to specify the first part (it actually expects the 4 boundaries).

The Even Rouault mentionned of using the VRT driver with `gdalwarp` and then use `gdal_translate -srcwin` to cut the tiles. But then the output is surprising: I get huge gaps that I can't explain. Here are the commands I use:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 \
    +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over" \
    -r lanczos -tr 30.92208077590933 -30.92208077590933 \
    -of VRT EU-DEM.vrt EU-DEM-corrected.vrt
```

The values for `-tr` are the size in meters of a pixel at the origin (which is 0x0°), calculated from the pixel size of the original data. Then the tiling:

```
$ gdal_translate -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZMA -co LZMA_PRESET=9 \
    -srcwin 0 0  16385 16385 -of GTiff EU-DEM-corrected.vrt 000x000-corrected.tif
    Input file size is 288000, 325220
    0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

$ gdal_translate -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZMA -co LZMA_PRESET=9 \
    -srcwin 16384 0  16385 16385 -of GTiff EU-DEM-corrected.vrt 001x000-corrected.tif
    Input file size is 288000, 325220
    0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Noticed I cut the two tiles at 0x0, 16384x0 and 0x16384 with size 16385x16385. I expect them to overlap, but then:

```
$ gdalinfo 000x000-corrected.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 000x000-corrected.tif
    000x000-corrected.tif.aux.xml
Size is 16385, 16385
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unnamed ellipse",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["unnamed",6378137,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-3896182.177764575928450,12932243.111789485439658)
Pixel Size = (30.922080775909329,-30.922080775909329)
Metadata:
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
COMPRESSION=LZMA
INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-3896182.178,12932243.112) ( 35d 0' 0.00"W, 75d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-3896182.178,12425584.818) ( 35d 0' 0.00"W, 73d46'32.64"N)
Upper Right (-3389523.884,12932243.112) ( 30d26'55.00"W, 75d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (-3389523.884,12425584.818) ( 30d26'55.00"W, 73d46'32.64"N)
Center      (-3642853.031,12678913.965) ( 32d43'27.50"W, 74d23'58.46"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
NoData Value=nan

$ gdalinfo 001x000-corrected.tif
[...]
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-3389554.806,12932243.112) ( 30d26'56.00"W, 75d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-3389554.806,12425584.818) ( 30d26'56.00"W, 73d46'32.64"N)
Upper Right (-2882896.513,12932243.112) ( 25d53'51.00"W, 75d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (-2882896.513,12425584.818) ( 25d53'51.00"W, 73d46'32.64"N)
```

These not only do not overlap, they're 1" apart! What could I be doing wrong?